# Unresponsive Facebook News Feed

Tags: facebook

I've been having problems for the last 2-3 weeks when visiting my Facebook News Feed in Chrome. The page never completely loads and makes Chrome unresponsive until I get the "Kill page" dialog.

Visiting a Facebook page (e.g. [this](https://www.facebook.com/cocacola)) will load, however navigating to my News Feed from there results in the same unresponsive page.

I've tried several things recommended on other sites, including disabling the cache and disabling the versions of Flash/Shockwave built into Chrome for the more up-to-date standalone version from Adobe. None of these have resolved my issue.

Looking at this in the Developer tools, I never see any console errors logged. I do see some image files in the Network tab that are never delivered.

Has anyone found a root cause for this issue and a means to stop it from occurring?

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: It does still happen. I've found that about every 6 months or so I need to change the browser I use to visit Facebook.

Comment: Hopefully it is some malware extension or tool with chrome or try reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have a malfunctioning browser extension that is affecting the page? check the chrome tools/extensions page